# jQuery weekpicker, firstDay set to Monday. But Sunday selects the wrong week

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have been trying to work this issue out for a long time now. I turned a datepicker into a weekpicker, however whenever I select a Sunday, it will select the next week instead of the selected week (Note: it will still highlight the Sunday of the selected week).

At first it seemed fine to keep Sunday as the first day, however I would like it to start with Monday, therefore I added the appropriate code. This was when the problem began to occur.

```
 $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
    firstDay: 1, <-----
    showWeek: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
```

I have created a rough [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvg6sa21/) to demonstrate the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated, also any questions feel free to ask as I know I may miss out on some much needed details sometimes. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You need to compensate for the difference between getDay and the setting of the firstDay being set to "1". Meaning, if it is set to Sunday, you need to go backwards from Sunday because Date.getDay always considers Sunday as '0' and as it doesn't respect the settings of the jQuery UI picker.

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x5z7xpk0/

```
    startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + (date.getDay() ? 1 : -6 ));
    endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + (date.getDay() ? 7 : 0 ));
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution! Thank you very much for this answer, can't believe I didn't take something like this into consideration. Much appreciated!